# need to select currency data from CSV

Tags: csv, select, currency

have a working select statement fro a CSV file but one columns (col3 specifically) is a dollar amount that is returning only an integer...dropping the positions to right of decimal.

Anyone have an idea what is happening?

Comment: Are you able to provide a small example of the SQL which produces this problem.  It would assist in helping you.